# Can not get response cookie from angular $http post using ionic

Tags: angularjs, cookies, response-headers, angular-cookies

I am sending a post auth request from my localhost to a remote server to get response cookies returned by server(using ionic proxy to solve CORS). From chrome network inspector, I can see the response cookie has been returned from server. However, I am not able to access it from $http post response. I try almost everything from other posts and I still can not get the cookie. What I have tried

- I use ngCookie and $timeout combination. Basically I get an empty object when I use $cookie.getAll() which I assume the cookie is not there
- I also set withCredentials to true
- I also tried headers.get('set-cookie')

My angular version is 1.5.3. Please help

Below is my code

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCookies'])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies, $timeout) {
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/api/User/Authenticate',
    data: {
      Username: 'xxx',
      Password: 'xxx'
    },
    withCredentials: true
  }).then(function(response) {
    $timeout(function() {
      console.log($cookies); // return {}
      console.log($cookies.getAll()); // return {}
    });
  }, function(response) {

  });
})
```

Here is the server response
[image]

Comment: can not able to determine why? It would be better if you can share your code.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: I can't see you're storing response in a cookie. Are you sure?

Comment: As you can see, the cookie is returned by server from screenshot. I can not even access it from angular how I can store it ???? Do you understand my question?

Comment: Did you include the angular-cookies.js file and please add dependency of `ngCookies` in app declaration.

Comment: Of course, otherwise I will get js error when I use $cookies. It just gives me an empty object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117369/discussion-between-eded-and-varit05).